# TSQL Between 2 dates or >= and <=?

Tags: t-sql

Morning experts.  I have a very simple query that I can not seem to get working as it should.

I have a table that has invoiceNumber, CustNum, Datetime, and Grand_total

I want to pull all transactions between a set of dates in this example all transactions between 4/10/2014 and 4/23/2014. I was using:

```
SELECT Invoice_number
,CustNum
,DATETIME
,Grand_Total
FROM invoice_totals
WHERE custnum = '10014877'
AND DATETIME BETWEEN '2014-04-10'
AND '2014-04-23'
ORDER BY DATETIME DESC
```

I just realized if there are any dates on 4/23 that this does not show them.. I have tried to substuite using:

```
WHERE custnum = '10014877'
AND DATETIME >= '2014-04-10' AND DATETIME <='2014-04-23'
```

But it is still giving me the same results (ignoring any transactions that occured on 4/23)
the last record pulling up has a datetime stamp of 2014-04-22 12:26:08.000.  There *ARE* 2 transactions on the 23'ed I am trying to include.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What about `<'2014-04-24'`?

Comment: what datatype is your DATETIME column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part:

```
AND DATETIME <='2014-04-23'
```

is actually(according to TSQL):

```
AND DATETIME <='2014-04-23 00:00:000'
```

So you're quering from midnight and missing all the transactions from 00:01 to 23:59 on the 23rd.

Try:

```
AND DATETIME <='2014-04-23 23:59:999'
```

Or

```
AND DATETIME < '2014-04-24'
```

Both should include all the transactions for the day of the 23rd.

Comment: No, the first of your fixes excludes any events that occur *during* the last minute of the 23rd.

Comment: You're correct, I tweaked the first one to include the last minute/second.

Comment: It's still not quite right. `23:59:59.997` would be correct *if* it's a `datetime` column. If it's a `datetime2` it should be some variant of `23:59:59.<some number of 9s>` but exactly how many depends on what precision has been specified for the column.

Comment: SQL will round off a datetime entered as 23:59:59.999 to 23:59:59.997 but the query as I wrote it is correct.  There wouldn't be any records for the last .002 as SQL would've rounded them to .997 in storing the record.

Comment: SQL disagrees with you: `select CONVERT(datetime,'2014-04-23T23:59:59.999')` produces `2014-04-24 00:00:00.000`

Comment: So in other words the first query(after the edit/update) becomes logically equivalent to the second query.  Either way they both work.

Comment: No, because in your first query (even if you do correct it so that the 9s are being used as milliseconds rather than seconds) you use `<=` and in the second you use `<`.

Comment: If you believe the answer can be improved on, please feel free to edit it.  My goal was to help the OP.

Comment: The OP is apparently happy. I don't want to materially affect your answer. But I'm hoping you'll recognise errors both in your answer and in your follow up comments. I.e. there is **no** situation in which SQL, presented with the string input `23:59:59.999` (in toto or as part of a larger string) will produce a (`time`, `datetime`, `datetime2`) value which includes a time component of `23:59:59.997`. A time input of `23:59:999` will universally produce an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with *continuous* data, such as datetimes, it's usually better to switch to using a semi-open interval - an *inclusive* start date and an *exclusive* end date. Exclusive end dates are usually easier to calculate:

```
WHERE custnum = '10014877'
AND DATETIME >= '20140410' AND DATETIME <'20140424'
```

I've also switched to a safe, unambiguous date format.

---

The alternative, using `<=` or `BETWEEN` (which is just shorthand for a pair of `>=` and `<=` comparisons, so your two queries were identical) requires an *inclusive* end date. Which depending on the exact data type you're using may be `2014-04-23T23:59:59.997` or `2014-04-23T23:59:59.9999` or any number of other possibilities - if you get it wrong and overspecify the value, it'll get rounded to be `20140424` and then an inclusive comparison is incorrect.

And even if you get it right today, it's a pain to find all usage of this pattern if the data type of the column changes later.

Answer (score 0):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive with respect to the boundaries.

However, I'm guessing that the type of your (poorly named) `DATETIME` field is .. **DATETIME**, so in the comparison, the date `'2014-04-23'` gets converted to a **DATETIME** as follows: `'2014-04-23:00:000'`. Thus, all records with `DATETIME` greater than that first moment on `04-23` are rejected.